# OpenGL white textures on other PC

Tags: opengl, textures, texture-mapping

I've made this small game using SDL + OpenGL. The game runs fine on my PC, but on a friend's PC, he just gets white boxes and blank screen.

I thought it might be an issue due to my textures being non power of 2 in dimensions. I cannot change the texture dimensions, so after some searching, I found that using **GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two** would somehow force(?) npot textures. But, to my surprise, the white boxes and stuff appear on my PC and they aren't even gone on my friends. I'm unable to understand what the problem is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
   numColors = images[i]->format->BytesPerPixel;
   if ( numColors == 4 )
   {
       if (images[i]->format->Rmask == 0x000000FF)
           textureFormat = GL_RGBA;
       else
           textureFormat = GL_BGRA;
   }
   else if ( numColors == 3 )
   {
       if (images[i]->format->Rmask == 0x000000FF)
           textureFormat = GL_RGBA;
       else
           textureFormat = GL_BGRA;
   }
   glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT,4);
   glGenTextures( 1, &textures[i] );
   glBindTexture( GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two, textures[i] );
   glTexParameteri(GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
   glTexParameteri(GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
   glTexImage2D(GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two, 0, numColors, images[i]->w, images[i]->h, 0, textureFormat, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, images[i]->pixels);
```

Comment: Does the white-box PC support NPOT-textures? That extension just

Comment: Sorry, stumbled on the keyboard. NPOT is not something you can enable, it's something the GPU supports (or not). so, is NPOT listed in the extensions string for the malfunctioning GPU?

Comment: Finding that out is not possible atm. The output images are from my own pc, one uses GL_TEXTURE_2D (correct one) and the other uses GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two (white boxes). Why do you think, using this ARB extension is causing problem?

Comment: You can't "use" GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two instead of GL_TEXTURE_2D?!?! Please post some code!

Comment: The thing is: I'm using GL_TEXTURE_2D, output is as desired. Switching to GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two, output is white boxes. The code is nothing but the regular functions used for texture mapping. Note that I'm changing this extension in all functions requiring it, glEnable, glBindTexture and so on. Do I need to change something else like the parameters for texture filtering or anything related?

Comment: @Macke : I've added code, check it out.

Comment: @tf61 GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two is NOT a texture target, using it as a enumeration generates a GL error, thus all your texture calls are being ignored. Use glGetError() to see the error.

Comment: So, those should remain GL_TEXTURE_2D? Doesn't work either though.

Comment: @tf61: What we're trying to say is that you should never send the GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two value to OpenGL. Use GL_TEXTURE_2D always, and adjust your textures & coordinates if the PC doesn't support NPOT. Also, see http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/texture_non_power_of_two.txt about what this extension exactly does.

Answer (score 1):

Your friend's video card may not support non power of two textures, therefore the output is still wrong despite using the GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two extension.

If your game relies on specific OpenGL extensions to display correctly, you should check for those extensions at start up and tell the user he can't run the game if his hardware is lacking the features.

Comment: I think that functionality depends on the driver, right? I'm asking that because I've seen the game run fine and bad on two systems both having the Intel G31 chipset (GMA3100 IGP).

Comment: If you want to check the extensions: A call to `glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS)` will return a space-separated string of extension names, which your application can parse at runtime.

Comment: @Yuri: My PC supports the ARB extension, but still output is white. Any ideas?

Comment: @tf61 well You can't really enable the extension. It is either supported and working or it is not supported at all. So the fact that you are getting white boxes now probably means you messed up somewhere, as it worked before. One workaround could be -albeit rather ugly- to rescale the images to powers of 2, and then read them in your program. If you then draw them on the same quads as before they will get rescaled back to their original. Other than that I'm out of ideas ...

Comment: I mean its working fine when I use the normal glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D) to glEnable(GL_ARB_...); I'm doing this for all the functions when texture mapping.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two instead of GL_TEXTURE_2D. Just check if the extension is supported then send NPOT textures using glTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, w, h, ...).

Call glGetError() to see if you're getting error. You should, since GL_ARB_...npot is not a valid value as you use it.

GL_ARB_NPOT is also used for 1D and 3D textures.

Comment: Hm.. that means if my PC supports NPOT textures, I shouldn't use GL_ARB. Thats fine. Can you suggest something for making this run on my friend's PC? If it doesn't NPOT totally, then do you think SFML will be able to draw npot textures?

Comment: I'm talking about the SFML(sfml-dev.org) library.

Comment: @tf61: You'll just have to pad your textures to the nearest POT (if memory allows), or gather them in a large texture (a.k.a. an atlas, this is also faster than separate textures). I don't know SFML but it might help you with that. No software library can change what the hardware supports, only add workarounds.

Comment: and everyone else: Thanks for your support. I've switched to SFML and everything works fine. If you want to check out the game, [here it is](http://tecfreak.co.cc/games/ach0.6.1beta.zip)

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to ARB_texture_non_power_of_two there's also another extension: GL_ARB_texture_rectangle; quite old, it's been supported by GPUs for ages. Using that your code would look like

```
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT,4);
glGenTextures( 1, &textures[i] );
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, textures[i] );
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, 0, numColors, images[i]->w, images[i]->h, 0, textureFormat, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, images[i]->pixels);
```

BTW: GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two is a extension name, not a valid token to be used as texture target; OpenGL should have issued an GL_INVALID_ENUM error.

Comment: Note that GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE uses integer non-normalized texcoord (i.e. 0...width instead of 0..1 as floats). But it could work.

Comment: From the OpenGL Extensions viewer, it seems that my graphics chipset supports the texture rectangle but when I use it, I'm getting undeclared identifier error.

Comment: @tf61: Please show some code how you use it. A full example was nice.